# Why won't Sequence work when wrapping a list of arguments for deletion with Remove?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, options, sequence, optional-arguments

I wrote a quick and dirty little function `freshStart` which does a variety of things meant to give me a nearly fresh Kernel without having to `Quit` the kernel. I want the function to have the `Option` of overriding the default `OptionValue` `symbols` `\[Rule] "Global\'*"` with a list of symbols to be removed. Problem is that `Remove` doesn't seem to play well with `Sequence`. How can I fix this?

Below is my little function...

```
freshStart::usage = 
  "freshStart resets $Line numbers, ClearSystemCache, and disposes of \
Symbols.";
Options[freshStart] = {symbols -> "Global`*", quit -> True};
freshStart[n_ : -2, OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{},
   Unprotect[In, Out];
   Clear[In, Out];
   Protect[In, Out];
   ClearSystemCache[];
   $Line = n;
   If[OptionValue@quit, Quit[], Remove@Sequence@OptionValue@symbols] //
     Echo
   ];
```

Here is the result of using Sequence. Notice that xyz and abc remain symbols even after running freshStart[] to remove then...

```
xyz = 123
abc = "my abc's"
echo@symbolQ@xyz;
echo@symbolQ@abc;
freshStart[n = 0, symbols -> {xyz, abc}]
echo@symbolQ@xyz;
echo@symbolQ@abc;
xyz
abc
```

Comment: Wouldn't one have to apply `Sequence` to a list, i.e., use `Sequence@@OptionValue@symbols`? But even that would not work becaue if `Sequence` is evaluated, then also the symbols are evaluated. So `Remove` would be called like this: `Remove[123, "my abc's"] ` and so nothing but an error message happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include `Print["opt=", OptionValue@symbols];` in your function and you will see, that the options are already evaluated. Therefore, you need a function with one of the Hold Attributs: HoldFirst, HoldRest, HoldAll,... to get the symbole name, not its value.

Here is one way to do it:

```
ClearAll[freshStart];
SetAttributes[freshStart, HoldFirst]
freshStart[symbols_List, n_ : -2] := Block[{},
   Unprotect[In, Out];
   Clear[In, Out];
   Protect[In, Out];
   ClearSystemCache[];
   $Line = n;
   Remove /@ Unevaluated[symbols];
   ];

abc = "my abc's";
xyz = 123;
freshStart[{abc, xyz}]
```

Then when you e.g. say:

```
?? xyz
```

You get:

Missing["UnknownSymbol", "xyz"]